# What is the significance or reason behind repeating a word in a row multiple times in a stotram?

Tags: sanskrit, stotra

This is about Mahisasura mardini stotram.

Some words are used more than once for example, in 11th sloka it is

> अयि सुमनःसुमनःसुमनः सुमनःसुमनोहरकान्तियुते
>
> Ayi Sumanah-Sumanah-Sumanah Sumanah-Sumanohara-Kaanti-Yute

Internet search only says what is Sumanah-s. I am aware of what is it but I do not understand the usage of it four times. There are more such instances here. It is not just about the meaning of particular word but I want to understand the intention of using one word more than ones in a row.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have seen that page and that does not say word by word meaning. So, asking here.

Comment: I do not think that is a good one to follow.. For example, for shiva shiva shumbha begining of 7th sloka it gives meaning for only shiva.. that word shiva is used twice there.. It does not say anything about that... In 11th sloka the word sumanah is used 4 times but it does not say anything about that...

Comment: Does asking meaning for one specific slokam considered on topic or off topic? I will forget about full stotram.. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: I have already done that.. If having "word to word" is a problem I can remove it.. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: AFAIK, the use of same word occurs more times due to use of **Alankara** such **Yamaka Alankara**, **Shlesh Alnkara** and **Latanuprasha Alankara**..each word might have different or same meaning..in this context [meanings](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=sumanas&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) seem to be beautiful, good minded etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is pure Sanskrit grammar Q related to Alankara...user is already aware of the meaning of verse but want to know grammar behind this...

Comment: @YDS I do not know the meaning of the verse.. I only know meaning of that one word..

Comment: @YDS you missed "It is not just about the meaning of particular word"..

Comment: @YDS I do not know what to say. Please feel free to edit this to make it suitable for this site. You can see my original question. SOme one asked me to edit it, I did it. Now you are asking me to edit.. If you think it is not good enough you can edit it or ignore it..

Comment: @YDS If you think this is off topic you can vote to close.

Comment: Repetition is emphasis that is also an Alankara. Jaya Jaya Jaya Jaya Hay is an emphatic wish/declaration in this case to the motherland.

Comment: @Narasimham I am not 100% sure if that is the case here.. Jaya Jaya Jaya hay is understandable.. not this... :O

Comment: When I first heard it I felt that such a repetition was to instill the notion of a fierce fearful aspect of the goddess was so only towards the ill-intentioned ones but is otherwise kindly disposed to all others in general,including the devotees.

Comment: You may continue discussion in chat room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the translation given [here](http://www.greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/mahishasura_mardini_stotram.php), Sumanah means "beautiful mind" throughout i.e in all the applications the word is having the same meaning.

But I have a small book published by the Ramakrishna Mutt called "Sri Mahishasura Mardini  Stotram" (consisting of three Stotras - the one discussed here, Bhavani Ashtakam by Adi Shankara and the Amba Stotram by Swami Vivekananda) according which the various Sumanahs found in the line have different meanings.

Following are the meanings of the various words in the line:

> Ayi - O Mother, 1st Sumanah (of superior qualities), 2nd Sumanah - of
>   the residents of Divyadhama or of heavens, 3rd Sumanah - grown in
>   their gardens, Sumanohara Sumanah - beautiful Parijata flower.

So, the overall meaning of this half verse is rendered thus:

> O Mother! You are endowed with  exquisite beauty of the flowers, that
>   are grown in the gardens of the good-souled residents of the heavens
>   ..

However, the meaning as per the already linked website is simply this:

> Ayi Sumanah-Sumanah-Sumanah Sumanah-Sumanohara-Kaanti-Yute
>
> 11.1: Salutations to You O Divine Mother; I Invoke You; Whose Beautiful Mind is United with a Charming Appearance

Comment: This is what I was expecting... Can you tell me name of the book

Comment: It is a very small book named "Sri Mahishasura Mardini Sotram". It has two more Stotras besides this one the names of which are already mentioned in the answer. @PraphullaKoushik I hv the book in Bengali.

Comment: Is it https://shop.advaitaashrama.org/product/sri-mahishasuramardini-stotram/ book? Is there an English version?

Comment: Yes that is the one. I am not sure if an English version of the same is there or not.. You can do a search @PraphullaKoushik

Comment: I searched but could not find. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: This is the correct and meaningful answer.

Comment: @Rickross - fantastic answer.Bravo.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated words are using for emphasizing something,
i.e. If someone helps us then we used to say thank you, and we trapped somewhere and someone takes out from that, then we used to say very very thank you.

Other examples are : 
good, very good, very very good, very very special, very very beautiful..
In short, if we want to emphasize on something we use such kinds of repeated keywords.
Same thing here in sloka 
सुमनःसुमनःसुमनः सुमनः tends for very very beautiful, gracious, wise, pleasant, good-minded etc.

Comment: I do not think repetition here means emphasizing..

Comment: In havan, you might often listen the keywords which spoken by the pandit, शांति: शांति: शांति: शांति:, 3 or 4 times repeated by bramhin.

Comment: I have said that already. I know some times repeating a word is emphasizing but here I think it is something else..